Azure VM (Debian 11.9) root directory 100% full...but its not!
Please help, I am at the end of my tether with this stupid VM!
Its an Azure VM running Debian 11.9 with a primary disk of 128GB and a secondary disk of 100GB.
It is reporting that / is currently 100% full.
root@SYS-801:/# df -h
Filesystem                                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                                     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                    791M   86M  706M  11% /run
/dev/sdb1                                                126G  126G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                    5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdc1                                                 16G  8.0K   15G   1% /swap/mntold/resource
/dev/sdb15                                               124M   11M  114M   9% /boot/efi
//logs.windows.net/sys                                   5.0T   23G  5.0T   1% /syslogs
tmpfs                                                    791M     0  791M   0% /run/user/1000

But its not, I think something is hidden somewhere but for the life of me I cannot find it.
I've spent 3 days solid trying different things and this is the current stat I am in.
The primary disk was originally 30GB and showing full so I increased it in Azure ans still its just eating up whatever I assign to it.
root@SYS-801:/# du -a -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr
du: cannot access './proc/490298/task/490298/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/490298/task/490298/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/490298/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/490298/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
27G     .
22G     ./syslogs
3.8G    ./var
1.1G    ./opt
779M    ./usr
236M    ./home
88M     ./run
77M     ./boot
5.6M    ./etc
68K     ./tmp
68K     ./root
16K     ./lost+found
12K     ./swap
4.0K    ./srv
4.0K    ./resource
4.0K    ./media
4.0K    ./<F1><F1><F1><F1>

As you can see, nothing is showing any larger than 22G so what is using up all of the extra space?
The only thing odd I can see is that the seconday 100GB isn't showing as mounted to anything.
root@SYS-801:/# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   100G  0 disk
└─sda1    8:1    0   100G  0 part
sdb       8:16   0   128G  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0 127.9G  0 part /
├─sdb14   8:30   0     3M  0 part
└─sdb15   8:31   0   124M  0 part /boot/efi
sdc       8:32   0    16G  0 disk
└─sdc1    8:33   0    16G  0 part /swap/resource

Does it matter that its appearing in the list first?
Along the way I have investigated the SWAP configuration within /etc/waagent.conf and turned off the swap feature to rule tis out.
# Format if unformatted. If 'n', resource disk will not be mounted.
ResourceDisk.Format=n

# Create and use SWAPfile on resource disk.
ResourceDisk.EnableSWAP=n

#Mount point for the resource disk
ResourceDisk.MountPoint=/swap/resource

#Size of the SWAPfile.
ResourceDisk.SWAPSizeMB=0

So I don't know what else could be clinging on to this space.
Rebooting doesn't change anything so I suspect it cannot be anything temporary.
As part of my cleanup I may have deleted too many directories from /, and I cannot create more:
root@SYS-801:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  lost+found  media  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  swap  sys  syslogs  tmp  usr  var
root@LIN-SYS-801-PRD:/# mkdir -p /mnt
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt’: No space left on device   
root@SYS-801:/# cd /mnt/root
bash: cd: /mnt/root: No such file or directory

Any clues where I can go from here?

Beckyboo, isn't this the same question you asked back in May? You've got essentially the same answer from telcoM and me.

@Chris Davies
You helped me a lot on this in chat so I thought I would summerise here what we did in case anyone else ever comes across this issue.
For some time I have been observing space issues on the root partition on SYS-PRD.
This is the desired mount points and their purposes.
Filesystem                         | Mounted on        | Purpose

/dev/sda1                          | /                 | Root partition

//syslogs.file.windows.net/sys-prd | /syslogs/sys-prd | Azure Storage for syslogs

/dev/sdc1                          | /mnt/resource     | The Microsoft Azure Linux VM Agent (waagent) swap file

The file system is being mounted at boot as expected
Therefore / is mounted on /dev/sda1
Shortly after boot, all dependencies load which includes system.d services starting up, including the rsylog daemon.
Syslogs start and are being collected before the mounted Azure storage can be mounted so therefore it is then creating the same directories under the root partition as it cannot find //syslogs.file.windows.net/sys-prd.
We need to ensure the the mounted storage in Azure gets mounted before rsyslog starts collecting logs.
Stop and disable the syslogger, rsyslog. Then we'll need to change the dependency so that the logger doesn't start until the disk is mounted
systemctl stop rsyslog; systemctl disable rsyslog

This snippet of code will report the disk usage for each directory that is hidden by a mount point:
mkdir /syslogs/sys-prd/backup
cd /mnt
mount --bind / /mnt
for mp in $(df | awk 'NR>1 && $NF != "/" {print $NF}'); do du -xhs /mnt"$mp"; done 2>/dev/null

mount --bind exposes a mounted filesystem at a new point in the filesystem but importantly without the subsidiary mounts. So here /mnt/syslog is shown as it is on / rather than from the mounted //syslogs.file.windows.net/sys-prd.)
The output, if healthy, should look like this
12K     /mnt/dev
4.0K    /mnt/run
4.0K    /mnt/dev/shm
4.0K    /mnt/boot/efi
4.0K    /mnt/syslogs/sys-prd

If however /mnt/syslogs/sys-prd is reporting high disk usage, take the following steps:
mv -v /mnt/syslogs/sys-prd /syslogs/sys-prd/backup

This will move all the temporary contents of /mnt/syslogs/sys-prd off the incorrectly mounted mnt point and onto the actual Azure storage. It can then be deleted from there if it is not needed.
Run the following command to list all of the current dependencies
systemctl list-dependencies

We are looking for the entry which corresponds to the Syslog mount in Azure which should display as syslogs-file\x2dlin\x2dsys\x2d801\x2dprd.mount
Then we need to add an exception to the dependencies to make the mount before syslog starts. We can do this by running systemctl edit rsyslog.service then entering this part at the top between the space, save and then reboot
[Unit]
After=syslogs-file\x2dlin\x2dsys\x2d801\x2dprd.mount

A reboot should unmount the temporary mount point. If you don’t reboot, you can run
umount /mnt

I hope this helps someone else as much as you helped me!

Since rebooting doesn't resolve the issue it's not deleted files that are still held open. I suspect you've covered the used disk with one of your other mount points. This snippet of code will report the disk usage for each directory that is hidden by a mount point:
mkdir -p /mnt/root
mount --bind / /mnt/root
for mp in $(df | awk 'NR>1 && $NF != "/" {print $NF}'); do du -xhs /mnt/root"$mp"; done 2>/dev/null

(In case you're not familiar with mount --bind it exposes a mounted filesystem at a new point in the filesystem but importantly without the subsidiary mounts. So here /mnt/root/syslog is shown as it is on / rather than from the mounted //logs.windows.net/sys.)
You should get close to zero disk usage for each resulting entry. For example,
12K     /mnt/root/dev
4.0K    /mnt/root/dev/shm
4.0K    /mnt/root/run
22M     /mnt/root/boot

What I think you'll find is that there is a significant disk usage reported for at least one entry (my guess would be your /syslogs). You can then review this by heading into /mnt/root/… and deleting or moving it as appropriate.
When you're done,
umount /mnt/root


As an aside, the last entry from your du looks strange: 4.0K    ./<F1><F1><F1><F1>. You might want to rename or delete that entry.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
